# How to statistically beat this dice game?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice, gambling

There is a dice game on this site where you can bet a video game's currency in games. I was wondering if any of the more statistically minded could come up with a way of beating the system?
The game's rules are as follows:

- The player may bet a certain amount of chips on rolling above or below a    certain number on a 10,000 sided die, whereby the odds are the same, eg 45% chance of winning, above 55.00 or below 45.00.
- The player must make a MINIMUM bet of 2500.
- The player can set their own multiplier and odds. The relation is such that at a 2x multiplier of the bet, the chances of winning are 45% and at 5x it is 18%
- The maximum bet is such that the multipier*bet is equal to 1 billion.
- The player is every half hour given 100,000 chips to bet.

Here is my strategy that I have been using:
Roll the 100,000 chips to 1 million.
Using a 5x multiplier, roll until lose 12 rolls on the lowest bet possible, then bet .2% of the cash stack, doing so two times if the first lost, then doubling the previous bet and so on until profit is made. The reason I bet double every two is that, because the odds of getting 13 losses is 0.82^13, eventually a win should turn out and the risk of loss only lowers. I have made it up to 3 billion chips, then lost them all when I got up to 200 million chip bets, which was max and kept on losing them.

Assuming the system is not rigged, how would you go about beating this game consistently?

Comment: Since the expectation of all admissible bets is negative, I'd bet as little and as slowly as possible in order to keep as many as possible of the $100000$ chips that I get for free every half hour.

Comment: Your strategy of doubling your bet after loses is similar to [Martingale Betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system))

Comment: Isn't this some over-complicated variant of the this principle? If yes, it doesn't work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)